# Continuing an interrupted batch

Tags: 8, batch-operations

I'm using a batch job in Drupal 8 to scrape pages from another site to import.

I'm using `httpClient`, and I have it wrapped in a try/catch.

```
try {
  $response = \Drupal::httpClient()->get($parts['scheme'] . '://' . $parts['host'] . $parts['path'], [
    'query' => $parts['query'],
    'headers' => array('Accept'=>'text/xml'),
    'verify' => FALSE,
    'connect_timeout' => 6,
    'CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER' => false,
    'CURLOPT_CERTINFO' => false,
  ]);
  return (string) $response->getBody();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  watchdog_exception('scrape', $e);
  return FALSE;
}
```

However, from time to time the remote site times out, and the guzzle exception is not caught, which causes the batch job to end.

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 500
Debugging information follows.
Path: /batch?id=44&op=do_nojs&op=do
StatusText: Internal Server Error
ResponseText: The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection() (line 186 of vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php). GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object, Object, Object) (Line: 103)
```

This job imports a few thousand pages, so when the error happens in the middle of the batch, it's a major pain.

I am getting ready to write a queue for the batch processor, where the batch pops a set of items off the queue and then marks them as done, so that I can continue the job after an exception.

But then I wondered, is there already a way to tell Drupal to continue a batch from where it left off or was interrupted? I did some googling and didn't find anything indicating that this feature already existed. I don't want to re-invent the wheel if I don't have to.

Can I re-start an incomplete, interrupted batch job?

Comment: were you able to figure this out, I am interested in the answer as well.

Comment: @awm I created a module that does batch queuing, I will try to release it shortly.

Answer (score 0):

So I think there is no way to tell batch to restart when it's gotten an error response. What you could do is to not return a possible error but rather re-try the request using your own wrapper. So could do

```
try {

  $TestRetry = new TestRetry();
  return $TestRetry->test();
}
// And I think you won't need this but handle the exception in your wrapper class.
catch (Exception $e) {
  watchdog_exception('scrape', $e);
  return FALSE;
}
```

and in your wrapper, you could attempt to retry the request to avoid an error. So your wrapper may look like this:

```
<?php

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
use GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler;
use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
use GuzzleHttp\Middleware;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;

class TestRetry {

  public function test() {
    $handlerStack = HandlerStack::create(new CurlHandler());
    $handlerStack->push(Middleware::retry($this->retryDecider(), $this->retryDelay()));
    $client = new Client(array('handler' => $handlerStack));

    $response = $client->request(
      'GET',
// @todo replace to a real url!!!
      'https://500-error-code-url'
    )->getBody()->getContents();

    return \GuzzleHttp\json_decode($response, TRUE);
  }


  public function retryDecider() {
    return function (
      $retries,
      Request $request,
      Response $response = NULL,
      RequestException $exception = NULL
    ) {
// Limit the number of retries to 5
      if ($retries >= 5) {
        return FALSE;
      }

// Retry connection exceptions
      if ($exception instanceof ConnectException) {
        return TRUE;
      }

      if ($response) {
// Retry on server errors
        if ($response->getStatusCode() >= 500) {
          return TRUE;
        }
      }

      return FALSE;
    };
  }

  /**
   * delay 1s 2s 3s 4s 5s
   *
   * @return Closure
   */
  public function retryDelay() {
    return function ($numberOfRetries) {
      return 1000 * $numberOfRetries;
    };
  }
}
```